# Numerical Analysis

Tags: numerical-methods

I am trying to determine some numerical difficulties that arise from a couple problems, and a good way to re-write them to avoid those errors.

For instance, I have:

1) $\sqrt{x+\dfrac{1}{x}} - \sqrt{x-\dfrac{1}{x}}$ where $x\gg 1$

I think that since these two terms approximately equal each other, there will be cancellation error. So I multiplied the numerator and denominator by the conjugate yielding:

$\dfrac{\dfrac{2}{x}}{\sqrt{x+\dfrac{1}{x}}+\sqrt{x-\dfrac{1}{x}}}$

I think that this should get rid of the cancellation error, does anyone see anything wrong with this attempt?

If this looks right, then I will show my attempt on the second problem, but I hope to verify my method first.

2) $\sqrt{\dfrac{1}{a^2}+\dfrac{1}{b^2}}$ where $a\approx 0$ and $b\approx 1$

Thanks!

Comment: There was no complex conjugate.   Just saying.

Comment: Haha thanks! I edited it, I just meant conjugate

Comment: Yes, your answer to (1) is correct.

Comment: I don't see a way to do 2) in the same way. There is not a conjugate of it that would make things disappear.

Comment: Is there really a need to do anything in (2)?  There is no cancellation to worry about here.

Comment: I think there is error, because the magnitude of the first term will be much less than the magnitude of the second term. So, in a computer, it may truncate some digits and ignore the first term. I was thinking of multiplying through by a^2 or something like that but I am still not certain that is the trick I am looking for.

Comment: Actually it's the second term that is much less than the first term here.  But when the second term is ignored, ignoring that second term does in fact give you a result as accurate as possible to the given number of digits.

Comment: Hmm, maybe then I should do the reverse of what I suggested. I am afraid of overflow and would like to prevent it. Perhaps:
1/b*(sqrt(1+b^2/a^2))

Comment: Nope - this leaves the problem term ($b^2/a^2$) inside the square root.

Comment: Under which values of x do you experience problems in either expressions? I am not aware of the exact value of re-writing the expression in your case. Could you provide an example?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For 1, you have successfully avoided the cancellation.  If you want, you could go to $$\frac {\frac 2x}{\sqrt x (\sqrt{1+\frac 1{x^2} }+\sqrt{1-\frac 1{x^2} })}=\frac 2{x^{\frac 32} (\sqrt{1+\frac 1{x^2} }+\sqrt{1-\frac 1{x^2} })}\approx x^{-\frac 32}$$  but I am not sure that is an improvement.

For 2, you could have $\frac 1{a^2}$ overflow where $\frac 1a$ does not.  To avoid this, you could rewrite it as $\frac 1a \sqrt {1+\frac {a^2}{b^2}}$.  That still squares $a$, but if it underflows maybe it gets set to zero and you are OK.